# Why is it correct "Do you enjoy swimming"?

Tags: exam-questions, present-continuous, present-simple

Do you enjoy _____?
- to swim
 -swimming
 -swim
 -to swimming

Can someone explain me why the answer is swimming and not swim or to swim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks for a noun to fill in the blank.  "Swimming" is the [gerund](https://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/part_1.htm) form of "swim", that acts like a noun.  Other examples:

> Do you enjoy **biking**?
>
> Do you enjoy **painting**?

The noun can be a longer *gerund phrase*:

> Do you enjoy **painting landscapes**?
>
> Do you enjoy **eating out at high-end Italian restaurants**?

The bare form of the verb ("swim") is not a noun, so that would not work in this question.  "To swimming" is simply not grammatical.

The infinitive form, "to swim" can also act like a noun.  The only reason it does not work here is convention.  With *enjoy*, the idiomatic convention is to use the gerund.  With other verbs such as *plan* or *like*, the infinitive is fine;

> Do you **plan to swim** this afternoon?
>
> Do you **like to eat out** at high-end Italian restaurants?

Unfortunately this is probably something you just have to memorize for each verb.

(edit) The other answer has been deleted, but it did contain a useful list of (at least most of) the verbs normally followed by gerunds:

> admit, advise, appreciate, avoid, can't help, complete, consider, delay, deny, detest, dislike, enjoy, escape, excuse, finish, forbid, get through, have, imagine, mind, miss, permit, postpone, practice, quit, recall, report, resent, resist, resume, risk, spend (time), suggest, tolerate, waste (time),

For example:

> Could you **imagine spending** the rest of your life with me?
>
> That high-end Italian restaurant **forbids smoking** anywhere on the property.